# How to hide Navigation Bar in embedded UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to present UIImagePickerController as a subview in ordinary UIViewController.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to hide the inner navigation bar (with "Chwile" title and "Anuluj" button). It looks something like this:

[image: iphone screenshot]

I tried subclassing UIImagePickerController with my custom controller. I also tried to style the NavigationBar property and achieved the following result:

[image]

However, I'd like to remove the Navigation Bar entirely. I tried to call `SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);` and `NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);` in `ViewWillAppear`, `ViewDidLoad` and also `ViewDidAppear` of custom image picker controller, but with no result.

Do you know how to remove the nav bar entirely? The solution in swift or obj-c is also perfect for me.

```
    private void PresentImagePicker(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type)
    {
        imagePicker = new CustomImagePickerController
        {
            SourceType = type,
            AllowsEditing = false,
        };

        imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
        imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

        AddChildViewController(imagePicker);

        ContentView.AddSubview(imagePicker.View);
        imagePicker.View.Frame = Content.Bounds;
        imagePicker.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        imagePicker.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding subview to parent view and managing frames, you can simply use presentViewController like this:

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So, you need to remove following these lines and replace them with just one line as above:

```
        AddChildViewController(imagePicker);
        ContentView.AddSubview(imagePicker.View);
        imagePicker.View.Frame = Content.Bounds;
        imagePicker.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        imagePicker.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
```

and it will work fine

Comment: but it is not showing anynavigation controller on picker