# IOS13, Hide imagepicker navigationbar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller, show-hide, ios13

This source works on all devices and simulators except IOS 13.

However, the navigation bar is not hidden on IOS13 devices.

Has anyone solved the same problem as me?

```swift
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
self.mainView.addSubview(picker.view)
picker.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Would you please try to present the pickerController instead of addSubView? Simply try to use this `self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
`

Comment: I have already done this, but the same problem arises.

Comment: Would you please try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702244/5167909

Comment: Except for ios13, my code works in the other versions. So I wonder if there is a special way of iOS13 alone.